# Using LINQ for Group and Sum

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm having trouble getting the grouped sum from a linq query. I am trying to get the net change for products between a certain date range. Right now my query runs and brings back the total quantity change for each transaction, but I can't get the sum. My query looks like this:

```
from t in Transactions
join p in Products on t.Product.ID equals p.ID
where t.TransactionDate >= DateTime.Parse("12/01/2015") && t.TransactionDate <= DateTime.Parse("12/31/2015")
orderby p.ProductCode
select new 
{
    Product = p.ProductCode,
    Description = p.Description,
    TotalQuantityChanged = (t.TransactionType.AddRemove == "Addition" ? (t.FullQuantity + (t.PartialQuantity / p.Pieces)).ToString() : (-1 * (t.FullQuantity + (t.PartialQuantity / p.Pieces))).ToString() )
}
```

And this returns

```
Product     Description                         TotalQuantityChanged

B107        3 ½" x 11" x 105" Kraft Faced R-11          23 
B107        3 ½" x 11" x 105" Kraft Faced R-11          -16 
X13AK       3 ½" x 11" x 105" Kraft Faced R-13          65 
X13AK       3 ½" x 11" x 105" Kraft Faced R-13          45 
X13AK       3 ½" x 11" x 105" Kraft Faced R-13          -12 
X45EX       3 ½" x 15" x 105" Kraft Faced R-15 HD       3 
X45EX       3 ½" x 15" x 105" Kraft Faced R-15 HD       36 
X45EX       3 ½" x 15" x 105" Kraft Faced R-15 HD       -7
```

but I have tried all manner of group by and sum with no luck. This is what the result should look like:

```
Product     Description                         TotalQuantityChanged

B107        3 ½" x 11" x 105" Kraft Faced R-11          7 
X13AK       3 ½" x 11" x 105" Kraft Faced R-13          98 
X45EX       3 ½" x 15" x 105" Kraft Faced R-15 HD       32
```

I've tried grouping like this, but I get an error in my where clause and in my select statement.

```
from t in Transactions
join p in Products on t.Product.ID equals p.ID 
group p by new { 
        p.ProductCode, 
        p.Description 
    } into g
where t.TransactionDate >= DateTime.Parse("12/01/2015") && t.TransactionDate <= DateTime.Parse("12/31/2015")
select new
{
    Product = g.Key.ProductCode,
    Description = g.Key.Description,
    TotalQuantityChanged = (t.TransactionType.AddRemove == "Addition" ? (t.FullQuantity + (t.PartialQuantity / p.Pieces)).ToString() : (-1 * (t.FullQuantity + (t.PartialQuantity / p.Pieces))).ToString() )
}
```

I am not understanding how to group or to get the sum. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why is everything a string??? less strings more types!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is roughly what you're going for:

```
from t in Transactions
join p in Products on t.Product.ID equals p.ID
where t.TransactionDate >= DateTime.Parse("12/01/2015") && t.TransactionDate <= DateTime.Parse("12/31/2015")
group t.TransactionType.AddRemove == "Addition" 
           ? t.FullQuantity + (t.PartialQuantity / p.Pieces) 
           : -1 * (t.FullQuantity + (t.PartialQuantity / p.Pieces)) 
    by new {p.ProductCode, p.Description} into g
select new 
{
    Product = g.Key.ProductCode,
    Description = g.Key.Description,
    TotalQuantityChanged = g.Sum().ToString()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @StriplingWarrior, using this I was able to get the query to work.